# How can I make label display cpu load Real time data

Tags: c#, wpf, label, cpu

I know how to get cpu load value using performance counter but have no idea how to make a label display it in real time

Answer (score 0):

Bind your label content to your ViewModel:

XAML (YourView.xaml.cs):

```
<Label Content="{Binding CPUText}" />
```

Your View Model would look like this:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public void GetCpuText()
  {
     //your code here.... 
     //it would populate your CPUText property...

     CPUText = .... (your code to get the cpu info)
  }
  private _cpuText;

  public string CPUText
  {
     get
     {
        return _cpuText;
     }
     set
     {
        _cpuText = value;

         NotifyPropertyChanged("CPUText");
     }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
  }
}
```

An example to make this work is to create your view, set the `DataContext` of that view to your ViewModel class:

```
var view = new YourView();
view.DataContext = new YourViewModel();
view.GetCpuText();
```